# Dart: How do I count items in 2d list

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart/Flutter.
I don't know how to count items from a 2d list.

```
List<List<bool>> a = [
    [true, true, false, false],
    [true, false, false, true]
];
```

I want to count `true` in this list, but in vertically.

So I want a result like this:

```
result = [2, 1, 0, 1]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the spread operator to assign length of inner list to a resultant array like this

```
 void main() {
   const a = [
    [true, true, false],
    [true, false, false, true, true]
];

  var result = [];
  for(var element in a) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var el in element) {
      if (el) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
    result = [...?result,count];
  }
  print(result);
}
```

try this code in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)

Comment: Your result is not match that I expected. But thank you.

Comment: modified the code now it shd give the result

Answer (score 0):

```
extension on List<bool> {
  List<int> addIfTrue(List<int> counter) {
    if (counter.length == length && counter.isNotEmpty) {
      var i = 0;
      forEach((e) => e ? counter[i++]++ : i++);
      return counter;
    }
    return [];
  }
}

void main() {
  var a = [
    [true, true, false, false],
    [true, false, false, true]
  ];
  var n = a[0].length;
  var z = a.fold<List<int>>(List.filled(n, 0), (prev, e) => e.addIfTrue(prev));
  print(z);
}
```

Result:

```
[2, 1, 0, 1]
```